# Extended Desktop causes Intel Graphics control panel to crash on Toshiba Portege R500-S5008X

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, intel-graphics, toshiba-laptop, extended-desktop

I am using a Toshiba Portege R500-S5008X with Windows XP SP3 and a Mobile Intel 945 Express Chipset graphics accelerator, running driver 6.14.10.4926. I can use an external monitor or Dual Display options just fine. When I try to use the Extended Desktop mode of the graphics control panel, and select OK or Apply, the display switches to only showing up on the primary device, and the "Confirm the Desktop Change" message box pops up, but I cannot interact with it. It appears that the Intel graphics control panel has crashed.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to fix this by installing the latest version of the software on Toshiba's web site instead of the latest version of Intel.